# How to configure ios fcm notification in AWS SNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using AWS SNS for push notification functionality in mobile apps, for Android in AWS SNS gcm option is there to register, for that i need to give fcm server key, for ios there is apple development,production for these I need to give p12 certificate so actually i wanted to use fcm in ios so where should i register

Comment: Hi skyshine. Your post is a bit confusing. Could you edit it out and point out the main concern and what are the main items that confuses you on registering

Comment: how to configure ios fcm notification in aws,right now we are using apple development and apple production in aws that is for apple push notification